# Trigger event on button inside div with same event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I trigger the onKeyDown on my button, and not the onKeyDown on my div, when one of my buttons is focused and a key down occur?
Even if the button is focused and I press a key, the onKeyDown on the div is triggered and not the onKeydDown on the button. How can I differ on which to take action?
I know there is something about the `event.stopPropagation();` but I have not make it work.

Example:

```
<div onKeyDown={handleKeyDownInDiv}>
  <button onKeyDown={handleKeyDownInButton} />
</div>
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Your code snippet looks like JSX, are you using a library? (If so, please include the relevant tags) And `stopPropagation()` should do what you need, please show how you have used it so far and we may be able to point out any problems with the implementation.

Comment: Yes, I am using React. Sorry for not mentioning that. I have now added a tag

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the event to not bubble up through the DOM. [Event bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/bubbles) is where an event, such as a click, will hit the target, followed by each parent element up until it reaches the top of the document.

You can simply use `event.stopPropagation()`:

```
<div onClick={() => console.log('div clicked')}>
  <button onClick={event => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('button clicked');
  }}>button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I am doing this, but I think there are some muffin going on with the event passed to the button. The Button component is "homemade" by someone, and the "on_click" prop is triggered both on onClick and onKeyDown. Maybe it is not the same event? Such that I can not prevent it from bubbling up?
If I understand `event.stopPropagation` it should go as far down as it can, and then stop triggering other event handlers on the way "upwards"? If I am misunderstanding, please explain it simple for me.

Comment: In that case, maybe try `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` instead. That prevents any other handlers from firing too.